# Laravel document root in a public hosting

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I just deployed a Laravel app into Hosting site, and place it into their folder like this:

```
"example.com/public_html/{All files in a laravel directoy}"
```

Now, if open in a browser, https://example.com it will show error

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php74/pear') in /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/public/index.php on line 34
```

my routes/web.php looks like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect()->route('login');
});
```

I already ran composer install and add htaccess to the inside public_html folder

The htacess, looks like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR] RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

Is my htaccess wrong, or is there any additional setup for Laravel if using htaccess to point index.php to public folder?

Note:
The hosting site, set the default document root to public_html and I can not change it. So in order to point to the public folder, I need to create .htaccess file

Comment: Just let your domain point to `public` folder. There is an `.htaccess` present already in `public` that will do the job (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/public/.htaccess). Why have you added another `.htaccess` to the Laravel root folder?

Comment: You should not put all Laravel files in `public_html`, that's the directory for the public files, the ones that are in the `public` directory of the Laravel app.

Comment: @JaviMollá This depends on how the hosting company is structuring it. For my partner company (a German one) the root directory is a directory like `public_html` and you can control the visibility using the domain mappings.

Comment: @Johannes The hosting site, set the default document root to public_html and I can not change it. So in order to point to the public folder, I need to create .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Place `.htaccess` file to your root folder and activate `mod_rewrite`.

Here's an example of what the file should contain without determining specific addresses:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

I think that it doesn't work in your case because of the condition rules.

Comment: My .htaccess same like you write. But still the have the same error when opening the index page. Can you give me more details about the condition rules?

Comment: My opinion, you should try remove your RewriteCond as usually hosting providers redirect requests to a specific folder by a domain name. Seems like you don't need them.

It's all provider specific though, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the Laravel contents in a directory that's hidden from the outside, one different than `public_html`. Let's suppose that it's `/home/user1/myapp`.
2. Move the contents of the Laravel `public` directory to the `public_html`. So, you should move `/home/user1/myapp/public/*` to `example.com/public_html`
3. Change the relative routes inside `index.php` to point to the directory of the first step.

Comment: But there are these two line in index.php: `use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;`. How does one resolve/change these paths?